# The route helper of fax resource can't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have generated a resource named "fax" in the users_manager engine:

```
apple@apple1:~/jiuhe/users_manager$ rails g resource users_manager/fax
      invoke  active_record
      create    db/migrate/20111129123558_create_users_manager_faxes.rb
      create    app/models/users_manager/fax.rb
   identical    app/models/users_manager.rb
      invoke    test_unit
      create      test/unit/users_manager/fax_test.rb
      create      test/fixtures/users_manager/faxes.yml
      invoke  controller
      create    app/controllers/users_manager/faxes_controller.rb
      invoke    erb
      create      app/views/users_manager/faxes
      invoke    test_unit
      create      test/functional/users_manager/faxes_controller_test.rb
      invoke    helper
      create      app/helpers/users_manager/faxes_helper.rb
      invoke      test_unit
      create        test/unit/helpers/users_manager/faxes_helper_test.rb
      invoke    assets
      invoke      js
      create        app/assets/javascripts/users_manager/faxes.js
      invoke      css
      create        app/assets/stylesheets/users_manager/faxes.css
       route  namespace :users_manager do resources :faxes end
```

And I wrote the configure/routes.rb

```
    UsersManager::Engine.routes.draw do
     namespace :users_manager do
    resources :users do
      resources :faxes
      resources :emails
      resources :qqs
      resources :addresses
      resources :telephones
    end
  end

  match "/:action"=>"users_manager/account"
  end
```

But the route helper users_manager_engine.users_manager_user_fax_path can't work.

Rails give me a message:

```
undefined method `users_manager_user_fax_path' for
 #<ActionDispatch::Routing::RoutesProxy:0x7f0ca0ab3520>
```

However the route helper users_manager_engine.users_manager_user_faxes_path exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check "rake routes" in the console, you'll discover that the singular of "faxes" in your routes is not "fax" but "faxis".
So the correct route would be users_manager_user_faxis_path

If you're not happy with that, you can edit or create a config/initializers/inflections.rb with

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.singular 'faxes', 'fax'
end
```